# How can I get a button's location on the canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a class that uses `System.Windows.Controls.Button`. What I want to do is to find the button location on the canvas.

Every tutorial out there that i found always uses the commands for WinForms Button class (System.Windows.Forms.Button) that has a location property: `bt.Location(Point)`. I can't change over my buttons so I need to find a way to get the button location with System.Windows.Controls.Button reference. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your button is on a `Canvas`, you can call `Canvas.GetLeft` and `Canvas.GetTop`.